# dataTables sorting column and loading page with no gamescore

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a website page at http://communitychessclub.com/examine.php

The problem is clicking on a row function to load the game works only on table rows with valid game records. The table header table row has column titles not game records. So when I click on a table header table row, the column sorts as it should, but then tries to load a game, but it can't.

```
$("#cccr").on("click", "tr", function() {
    window.location.href = 'basic.php?game=' + $(this).attr('game');
```

Can this be fixed? This is the complete script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cccr').DataTable({
        "createdRow": function(row, data, index) {
            $(row).attr('game', data.game);
        },
        "search": {
            "search": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"
        },
        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        "keepConditions": true,
        "paging": true,
        "deferRender": false,
        "oSearch": {
            "sSearch": "<?php echo ($_GET['player']); ?>"
        },
        "aaSorting": [],
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bSort": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "sPaginationType": "numbers",
        "responsive": true,
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "stateSave": false,
        "ajax": "assets/games.ajax",
        "pageLength": 6,
        "columns": [{
            "data": "Date",
            "width": "7rem",
        }, {
            "data": "Event"
        }, {
            "data": "ECO"
        }, {
            "data": "White"
        }, {
            "data": "WhiteElo"
        }, {
            "data": "Black"
        }, {
            "data": "BlackElo"
        }, {
            "data": "Result"
        }, {
            "data": "game",
            visible: false
        }]
    });

    $("#cccr").on("click", "tr", function() {
        window.location.href = 'basic.php?game=' + $(this).attr('game');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this click function just table rows(tbody tr) not for table header row(thead tr). Actually, you just want click tr elements under the tbody element.

```
$("#cccr").on("click", "tbody tr", function() {
window.location.href = 'basic.php?game=' + $(this).attr('game');});
```

Comment: Simple succinct and perfect!